# Is there a way to insert multiple values using single statement in sybase

Tags: insert, sybase

I have 200-300 values to be inserted in a table. i don't want to write insert statement 200 times. is there any short way to do it? I have tried

```
insert into #nodes (nodes) values 
('100161'),('100164'),('102226'),('100143'),('108942'),('106922'),('108949'),('107191'),
('100098'),('107182'),('107193'),('98646'),('100102'),('100105'),('103044'),('103293'),
('103296'),('103297'),('104178'),('103018'),('104145'),('103017'),('103019'),('108991'),
('108995'),('109000'),('103020'),('102121'),('103021'),('106284'),('103951'),('100117'),('102872'),
('102873'),('100125'),('101582'),('102234'),('103027'),('103028'),('102225'),('101574'),('106964'),
('106969'),('108956'),('109719'),('101581'),('102346'),('106997'),('107028'),('107030'),('107031'),
('107070'),('102347'),('107083'),('107084'),('107085'),('107086'),('103633'),('107124'),('100191'),
('100172'),('100204'),('104148'),('104163'),('100190'),('107180'),('109849'),('109852'),('110047'),
('107473'),('107502'),('100091'),('100096'),('106265'),('108346'),('108222'),('109382'),('107814'),
('107823'),('108167'),('109359'),('100171'),('103300'),('108268'),('108300'),('108860'),('108982'),
('102342'),('102344'),('100089'),('108675'),('108880'),('109341'),('109875'),('109877'),('109884'),
('108854'),('101912'),('102829'),('103317'),('104323'),('104324'),('104389'),('107239'),('108271'),
('108273'),('108275'),('108277'),('108279'),('108872'),('108885'),('108957'),('108983'),('109878'),
('109148'),('109279'),('109399'),('109443'),('109922'),('103318'),('109448'),('109452');
```

Bt this doesn't seem to work in sybase

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean Sybase ASE: indeed, the 'array insert' is not supported. YOU have to do individual INSERT-VALUES for a single row. 
Alternatively, you could define a temporary table with N columns and insert N values at a time, and then afterwards run N INSERT-SELECT statements to move those values from the temp table into your target table.